# If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ continous function then $f([a,b])$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, solution-verification

> If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ continous function then $f([a,b])$ is bounded (duplicate and verifying attempt)

I am trying to prove this problem, can you check if this is true?

Here is my attempt:

Let $a_1=a$, $b_1=b$ and $I_1=[a_1,b_1]$, then let $a_2=a_1$, $b_2=\frac{b_1+ a_1}{2}$ and $I_2=[a_2, b_2]$ and let $a_{n+1}=a_n$, $b_{n+1}=\frac{b_n+ a_n}{2}$, recursively. Lastly, $I_n=[a_n,b_n]\subseteq [a,b]$. We can obserwe  $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to a$ . If we write the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the continuity at a, then$\forall \epsilon >0$; $\exists \delta >0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. Since $I_n$ intervals are neighbors of $a$, we can modify the definition as follows $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ ($\forall n>0$ and $\forall x \in I_n$) also we can get $|f(x)|<1+|f(a)|$ if we take $\epsilon=1$. Now assuming $f$ is not bounded on $[a,b]$, $n_0>0$ and $\exists x \in I_{n_0}$ $|f(x_0)|>n_0$ . In the definition we gave using $I_n$ intervals which are neighbors of $a$, it continues to work if we take $n=n_0>|f(a)|+1$  but here we get $|f(x_0)|>n_0>|f(a)|+1$ this means $|f(x_0)|>|f(a)|+1$ and $|f(x_0)-f(a)|>1$ This gives the contradiction that the function f is not continuous for $\epsilon=1 $ at point $a$. Then our assumption that f is not bounded is false, which proves the correctness of our claim that $f([a,b])$ is bounded.

---

I am not sure after the last part $n=n_0>|f(a)|+1$

Comment: Your proof can be corrected in this manner. If $f$ is unbounded on $[a, b] $ then it is unbounded on one of the subintervals $[a, (a+b) /2],[(a+b)/2,b]$ and let $[a_1,b_1]$ be that subinterval where $f$ is unbounded. Bisect it again to get a smaller subinterval $[a_2,b_2]$ where $f$ is unbounded and continue to get a sequence of subintervals $[a_n, b_n] $. Show that $a_n, b_n$ tend to a common limit, say $c$, which lies in $[a, b] $. Get a contradiction using continuity at $c$ (same as you have done at $a$)

Answer (score 2):

> Since $I_n$ intervals are neighbors of $a$, we can modify the definition as follows $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ ($\forall n>0$ and $\forall x \in I_n$)

This is the point your solution goes off the rails.  You haven't used continuity at any point other than $a$, but at this point, only using $f$ is continuous at $a$, you've already concluded that $f$ is bounded.

The strongest correct statement I can give in place of that one is

> Since $I_n$ intervals are neighbors of $a$, we can modify the definition as follows $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ (there is some $N>0$ such that $\forall n>N$ and $\forall x \in I_n$)

which effectively is just saying $f$ is bounded on *some* $I_n$.

There are some later statements that need doctored too, in order to make any sense of them, but it doesn't actually matter because **there is no valid way to conclude $f([a,b])$ is bounded if you only use the assumption that $f$ is continuous at $a$ and not on the entirety of $[a,b]$**.

Comment: I tried to get a contradiction here by using the continuity at point a. Unfortunately, I couldn't think of any other method.

Comment: @Hacemat I don't know what methods are accessible to you, but needless to say you need to use a method that is able to use the continuity of $f$ at arbitrary points of $[a,b]$.  For instance, if you know that $[a,b]$ is sequentially compact, then you should let $x_n$ be some point in $[a,b]$ such that $|f(x_n)| \geq n$ and consider the sequence of the $x_n$.  Then continuity at any of its subsequential limits will give a valid proof with the same flavor as your attempt.

Comment: I can only use basic calculus, we are not allowed to go into compactness and sequences. I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: @Hacemat You're welcome.  Do note that you have to _use_ the compactness of $[a,b]$ somewhere in your argument, even if you cannot _quote_ its compactness.  If the terms "compactness" and "sequential compactness" are somehow disallowed, then look through your text at whatever theorems either use $[a,b]$ explicitly or are for "closed and bounded sets".